# I2C not working between LPC824 and MMA8453Q

Tags: scope, accelerometer, i2c, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

For a project I am using an LPC824 MCU from NXP and I want to read out data from the accelerometer over I2C. This accelerometer is the MMA8453Q. Looking into the datasheet of the accelerometer I see the following:

[image: I2C timing]

From my understanding this means that you give a start signal, you write the device address and put write behind it, you get an acknowledgement and so on.

The address I have to write is the following:
[image: adress table]

the register I chose for now was 0x0D which is the "Who am I" register, this should always be read as 0x3A.

For people familiar with NXP examples I based myself on one of them. This is the code I have atm:

```
*txData = 0x0D;
        SetupXferRecAndExecute(0x1C, txData, 1, rxData, 0);
        SetupXferRecAndExecute(0x1C, txData, 0, rxData, 1);
```

and this is what it looks like on the scope
[image: scope image]

So as i can see I send the Device adress twice, first I write the register address and than i want to read it, but it gives 0x00 back.
Can someone pls help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on those data sheets:

- MMA8453Q: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8453Q.pdf
- LPC82X: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC82X.pdf

LPC82X is the Master and MMA8453Q is the Slave.

Depending on if you set the pin 7 of the slave to high (SA0 = 1) or low (SA0 = 0) your 7-bit salve address is either 0x1D or 0x1C. Together with the read (1) or write (0) bit the final 8-bit address is as written in the table you have posted in your comment.
For the further example, let's assume SA0 is set to low, means the full 8-bit slave address is 0x3B for reads and 0x3A for writes.

Let's assume you want to read out the single-byte register 0x17, which is the freefall/motion event source register.

Now, the message sequence (that you also showed in your post) is as follows:

1. Master sends: Start Signal
2. Master sends: Slave Address + Write-Bit (in our case 0x3A)
3. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
4. Master sends: 0x17 (as we assumed you are interested in the content of that
   register)
5. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
6. Master sends: repeated Start Signal
7. Master sends: Slave Address + Read-Bit (in our case 0x3B)
8. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
9. Slave sends: content of register 0x17
10. Master sends: NACK
11. Master sends: Stop Signal

If you want to read out registers like of the MMA8453Q (such as OUT_X_MSB/LSB) which contain two bytes your sequence would be the following:

1. Master sends: Start Signal
2. Master sends: Slave Address + Write-Bit (in our case 0x3A)
3. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
4. Master sends: 0x01 (as we assumed you are interested in the content of that register)
5. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
6. Master sends: repeated Start Signal
7. Master sends: Slave Address + Read-Bit (in our case 0x3B)
8. Slave sends: ACK (done by hardware)
9. Slave sends: MSB of register 0x01
10. Master sends: ACK
11. Slave sends: LSB of register 0x01
12. Master sends: NACK
13. Slave sends: Stop Signal

It is important for the Master to know in advance how many bytes will be received when requesting the data from a particular register of the slave. Only with that knowledge, the master can send the proper amount of ACK before sending the last NACK followed by the Stop Signal.